# ColdFusion cleanUp method was not found, unable to kill session

Tags: java, coldfusion

I just moved our sites from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2008 R2 server.  Everything appears to be working correctly except for one line of code.

```
<cfset CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker').cleanUp(application.applicationName, sid) />
```

We are seeing this error:

> The cleanUp method was not found.
>   Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types, or the cleanUp method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that matched the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, you may need to use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity."

I have made sure all files were copied to the new server, all settings are the same, I even cleared the ColdFusion class cache and restarted the server.  Below is the full code of the function.  What would cause this and how do I fix it?

```
<cfif isDefined("session.CFID") AND isDefined("session.cftoken")>
    <cfset sid = session.cfid & '_' & session.cftoken />
    <cfset CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker').cleanUp(application.applicationName, sid) />
</cfif>
```

**UPDATE**

I stripped this down to the bare minimum. I've found this same basic code on several sites.  The first three lines work fine.  As soon as I try and assign the userSession, I get a 500 server error.

```
<cfset app = application.applicationName>
<cfset sessionTracker = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker')>
<cfset sessionCollection = sessionTracker.getSessionCollection(app)>
<cfset userSession = sessionTracker.getSession(app, sessionID))>
```

I can dump the sessionTracker and confirm, sessionID is a valid value.

Comment: Did you also upgrade Java and/or ColdFusion?

Comment: Try to create an object of `coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker` and then dump it.  See if there is a cleanup() method.  This will help you isolate the problem/

Comment: ColdFusion version remains the same.

Comment: The cleanup() method worked for many years on the old server and this new server has the same version of ColdFusion.

Comment: *ColdFusion version remains the same* Are you certain? What is the exact version? That method does not exist in CF10+. As it is an internal (undocumented) method, unfortunately it is always possible it changed or it went away in later versions.

Comment: CF8.  Same issue as discussed in this blog article:  http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/11/can-you-run-some-code-for-me-please.html

Comment: Ohh... I forgot about that. Just checked it with `javap -s` and it is there in CF11, but ... it is marked as  "protected". So it cannot be accessed outside the package. That could explain why it does not show up in cfdump. Though not why Adam and I got different results with the same version :/ Unfortunately I do not have CF8 to test with.

Comment: If you have a JDK installed (not JRE) you can run `javap -s` and see if the method is public, protected or private in CF8.